# TFS API Request - Authorization and Authentication Setup

Tags: authentication, tfs, asp.net-web-api2, authorization, tfs-sdk

What would I need to do in terms of setup and configuration if I want to build an API that I plan to deploy and host on a virtual machine in azure. That Web Api would make calls to our on premise TFS instance to perform continuous integration processes such as creating, getting, and kicking off builds and releases? Do I need a token, some special permission, etc..

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT The first answer by ChamindaC was somewhat helpful. but your answer to another post similar to this was extremely helpful and it was exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TFS REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/xamlbuild/requests#request-a-build) and use [Personal Access Token (PAT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate) to authorize. When defining PAT you can decide [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth#scopes) based on the request that you are going to make.

Answer (score 0):

Also you may try build and release integration for DevTest labs: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuredevtestlabs.tasks